# How to call mapStateToProps in react component to get Redux stores

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to get the Redux state that is stored to be set to a component's props. My components implementation is below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Characters extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log('props', this.props);
        return(
            <div>
                <h4>Characters</h4>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        characters: state.characters
    }
}

export default connect()(Characters);
```

I have my reducers set up like following. Now my `console.log()` is printing out a dispatch object not the props. I am not sure what else I need to do to set the component's props. I have tested my reducers and they seem to work fine. I am having trouble setting the component's props to the redux store. Below is my main reducer.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import characters from './characters_reducer';
import heroes from './heroes_reducer';

const rootReducers = combineReducers({
    characters,
    heroes
});

export default rootReducers;
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong here. A little help and a hinge to the right direction would help a lot. Thanks :)

Comment: your forgot to add mapStateToProps to connect()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to pass mapStateToProps to connect:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Characters);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in your actionCreators and your mapStateToProps function to the connect function in order to be able to access the store from the component:

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Characters);`